# Create a slideshow for top stories

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to create a object that scrolls through different pictures with links to the stories that go with the picture. I am not sure what they are called, but its pretty much a news slideshow with links. Much like the one on leagueoflegends.com, espn.com, liverpoolfc.tv.

Does anyone know where to find a tutorial or something like that? I have not worked with Javascript much before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be describing a carousel. There are hundreds of these available for use, including [this one that I wrote](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/Uber-customsiable-video-carousel-148) a while back (it's primarily for video, but is perfectly usable with pictures, too) or [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Comment: This works great. I am using the one that you wrote (awesome btw). MY question for you is how can i adjust the size of the images that are displayed on the inside? I can adjust the outer border, but cannot find where the inside "content" part changes. If it helps, I am trying to make it fit in a space that is 540px wide. The height does not really matter, just w/e looks good within 540px (not exact just has to be <540)

Comment: Glad you like the carousel. Its behaviour and dimensions are controlled by the XML config file. See [here for details](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/Uber-customsiable-video-carousel-148#part4). Specifically, to change the size of the slides, you need the settings at `root/settings/slides/width` and `root/settings/slides/height`.

Comment: Thanks! I will see if I remember to send you a link of my final site when I am done so you can see your creation is very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try jQuery SerialScroll plugin.

It works great.

I used it in many of my projects.

URL : [jQuery SerialScroll Demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/)

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of great sliders out there. Two that I've used many times are the BXSlider and the Anything Slider.

http://bxslider.com

http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/